# Visual Studio automatically excluding added files from Git for externally referenced project

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a solution. The solution has five projects. Four of the projects are local to the solution. One of the projects was created as part of another solution so that it can be referenced by multiple solutions during active development. I will refer to this project as the "external" project. The "external" project will eventually become a nuget package, but during active development, it is easier to reference the existing project in the solution on which work is being done. The only issue is that files added to the "external" project are automatically excluded from Git source control (the red minus sign icon appears next to the file). The file can be added manually by right-clicking on it, selecting Git, and then selecting "Add ignored file to source control". It's an annoyance more than anything, but perhaps someone has an answer for why this extra step is necessary?

I have checked the .gitignore file. It is not the problem. I can add files to any of the other projects without needing to include them in source control manually. The problem is only in the "external" project.

[image: snip]

Comment: You say it's not the `.gitignore`, but everything you're saying suggests that it **is**. What does your `.gitignore` look like?

Comment: My .gitignore is the Visual Studio default added by Azure Devops, so it contains a lot of stuff. The fact is that it has not been edited by anyone unless Visual Studio is doing so automatically. Even if Visual Studio is editing the file, there are no changes detected to check in to Devops. The .gitignore file in Devops is exactly the same as the day the solution was created.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue with a demo, when the affected class is added to `.gitignore`.

[image]

Expect for explicitly adding the `Class1.cs` file like `/ConsoleAppDemo/Entities/Class1.cs`, we need to check as well if this class is impacted by any other file/path pattern in `.gitignore`. Here are some samples you may pay attention to.

```
**/Class1.cs
*[Cc]lass*.cs
```

Hope the information could help.